# Second jQuery Validate does not works inside Bootstrap tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, jquery-validate

I've two tabs in my homepage, one for personal registration and another to companies. The validation works fine in the first, but in the second tab, the validation don't work and returns nothing.

First of all, the HTML:

```
<!-- Fire nav tabs -->
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#pf" data-toggle="tab">Pessoa Fisica</a></li>
    <li><a href="#pj" id="pjHandler" data-toggle="tab">Pessoa Juridica</a></li>
</ul>

<!-- Nav tabs -->
<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="pf">
        <form id="pfRegister" action="" method="post" autocomplete="off">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" id="firstName" class="form-control inputSk" placeholder="Name" name="firstName" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" id="lastName" class="form-control inputSk" placeholder="Surname" name="lastName" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" id="email" class="form-control inputSk" placeholder="Email" name="email" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="password" id="password" class="form-control inputSk" placeholder="Password" name="password" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="password" id="confirm_password" class="form-control inputSk" placeholder="Confirm your password" name="confirm_password" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                 <select id="gender" name="gender" class="form-control inputSk" required>
                     <option value="">Gender</option>
                     <option value="Male">Male</option>
                     <option value="Female">Female</option>
                 </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class='input-group date'>
                    <input type='text' class="form-control inputSk input" name="birth" id="birth" required>
                 </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="actionForm">
            <button type="submit" id="send" class="btn btn-default sk skBtn-primary submit">Sign up</button>
        </div>
    </form>
    </div>

<!-- company register -->
<div class="tab-pane fade" id="pj">
        <form id="pjRegister" class="captcha" action="" method="post" autocomplete="off">
            <div class="form-group">
                 <input type="text" class="form-control inputSk" name="cnpj" id="cnpj" placeholder="CNPJ" required>
             </div>
             <div class="form-group">
                 <input type="text" class="form-control inputSk" name="juridicIdentity" id="razaosocial" placeholder="Razao Social" required>
             </div>
             <div class="form-group">
                 <input type="text" class="form-control inputSk" name="companyIdentity" id="company" placeholder="Company Name" required>
             </div>
             <div class="form-group">
                 <input type="text" class="form-control inputSk" name="administrator" id="administrator" placeholder="Administrator Account" required>
             </div>
             <div class="form-group">
                 <input type="email" class="form-control inputSk" id="pjEmail" name="pjEmail" placeholder="Email" required>
             </div>
             <div class="form-group">
                 <input type="email" class="form-control inputSk" id="pj_confirm_email" name="pj_confirm_email" placeholder="Confirm Email" required>
             </div>
             <div class="form-group">
                 <input type="password" id="pjPassword" class="form-control inputSk pwstrength_viewport_progress" placeholder="Password" required>
             </div>
             <div class="form-group">
                 <input type="password" id="pjConfirm_password" class="form-control inputSk" placeholder="Confirm Password" required>
             </div>
             <div class="actionForm">
                  <button type="button" id="pjSend" class="btn btn-default sk skBtn-primary submit">Sign up</button>
             </div>
         </form>
    </div>
    </div> <!-- end of pj panel -->
```

The JS:

```
$("#pfRegister").validate({
    rules: {rules},
    messages: {msgs}
});

//companies validator
$("#pjRegister").validate({
    rules: {rules},
    messages: {msgs}
});
```

The defaults and `showErrors` is set inside `$.validator.setDefaults`.

I tried to validate one by one with this, but still not working:

```
var pfreg = $("#pfRegister").validate({
    rules: {rules},
    messages: {msgs}
});

//companies validator
var pjreg = $("#pjRegister").validate({
    rules: {rules},
    messages: {msgs}
});

pjreg.element('input');
pfreg.element('input');
```

Searching the web, I found a possible solution:

```
$("#pjRegister").each(function(){
    $(this).validate();
});
```

But this way the form don't validate when I click the Submit button.

Comment: i need you show code html, for help

Comment: Please include the relevant HTML and CSS in your question, along with a mockup on jsfiddle or bootply if you could.

Comment: Editing right now. The HTML is too long, I'm deleting the unnecessary code.

Comment: The `.each()` solution you are trying has nothing to do with any of this.  `.each()` can only be used when you're selecting more than one form at a time.  Obviously, you're only targeting one form with an id selector, so `.each()` is totally pointless.

Comment: I added the HTML now, inside the bootstrap tabs. Outside the tabs, the validations works fine, the problem is when the form is inside.

Comment: @Sparky About the `.each` I tried to change the code to: `$("form").each(function(){
    $(this).validate();
});`
But still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first button is a `type="submit"`, which is captured automatically by the validation plugin, so validation is triggered.

Your second button is a `type="button"`, which is **not** captured, so the plugin does nothing when you click it.

**Working DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/9o0zd4pt/1/**

Comment: Thanks @Sparky, I can't believe I lost hours of work because this. Going to do a /quit of this life now.

Comment: @WilliamKennedy, sometimes it helps to slow down and methodically attack it.  After all, if it works on one and not the other, it's time to carefully examine the two for differences.

Comment: You're completely right. Thank you one more time :)